# Free Asset management software

Tags: gratis, inventory, asset-management

I'm looking for a software that can work on PC (web or installed,doesn't matter) and Android. I need it to record who from my staff has certain assets. These assets are mainly laptops, phones, printers, and few other items like projectors and minor assets.

We currently do it in an excel sheet, and it's getting tedious to maintain as our assets and office grows in size.

I just need something where I can specify this asset moved from person X to person Y, or moved back to stock. I don't care for GPS tags. I don't care about network discovery. I do care about it having a mobile app that syncs with the main software. I don't care if it's self hosted or in the cloud, I'm more than capable of maintaining the software and connecting the app to it, if needs be.

Comment: For android - must it be able to be used offline? Can it be a mobile able webpage as well or do you need an installed app?

Answer (score 1):

Snipe-IT

https://www.snipeitapp.com/

No mobile apps but the first thing they say:

> Mobile-friendly for asset updates on the go

https://www.snipeitapp.com/product

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/62592)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try 10-Strike Network Inventory Explorer (more details are here [1](https://www.10-strike.com/networkinventoryexplorer/)). It is developed just for the routine like that.
It automatically scans PCs and collects data on the software and hardware. But also you can add information manually: where you've moved an asset, to what person, where, and so on. Much more convinient than an excel sheet.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a Microsoft account? If not, it’s free to sign up for an account. You can then sign up for a free trial of PowerApps which is a low code or no code app maker.

There is actually an asset management template available, all ready to go with sample data included that can easily be deleted. You can then connect your excel data which you seem to have already, so you’d even have past data to look at in the app as well as the ability to add in whatever you need from there on.

PowerApps can be accessed via android or iPhone (and the web), and they are also accessible if service/internet cuts out.

The asset management app is very simple but still has those items you mentioned wanting. You could add and delete whatever you wanted, too. It’s almost 100% customizable to do whatever you want an app to do.

The cost of the subscription after the free trial comes in different tiers and offers based off many things, so it could even end up being free if you’re eligible for the nonprofit grant. I use PowerApps because of the grant. It took some time to learn how to make more complex apps because of the coding part, but it’s possible to make apps without code. There are pages and pages of resources through Microsoft’s website alone where you can take courses to learn PowerApps or even attend a live webinar/course.

Maybe you’ve found something by now, but if not, I hope you’re able to find a way that works for you! And, please let me know if you need more info. I’m still a beginner, but I’ll do my best to help.

-Missy